# Problems changing a void pointer value in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Basically my problem is that i'm trying to change the value inside the `valor` variable, so that after calling of the `cambiar_valor` function it chenges to 25. But my problem is that it doesn't chang at all. What am i doing wrong here?. I'm trying to make a really generic function so that depending of the data type i pass to the function it changes dinamically. In this case is an integer type but what i'm trying to do here is to check if i could change the value of the `valor` variable inside the function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void cambiar_valor(void* valor,int* valor_dos) {//assign valor_dos to valor
    valor = valor_dos;
}

int main() {
    void *valor;
    int *valor_dos = 25;
    cambiar_valor(valor,valor_dos);
    printf("%d \n",(int*)valor);//this should show 25
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your function

```
void cambiar_valor(void* valor,int* valor_dos) {//assign valor_dos to valor
    valor = valor_dos;
}
```

You are passing in the pointers by value, meaning that `valor` and `valor_dos` are copies of the parameters you pass in.  Reassigning `valor` inside the function has no effect on the calling function.

To fix this, take the parameters in by pointer:

```
void cambiar_valor(void** valor, int* valor_dos) {//assign valor_dos to valor
    *valor = valor_dos;
}
```

Then call

```
cambiar_valor(&valor, valor_dos);
```

Also, as @Levon has mentioned, your initialization of `valor_dos` in `main` is incorrect and will probably cause a segfault at runtime.  You might want to change that as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works now, but i'd like to know wich is the best way to declare the pointer because of what you said, i always thought that when i do `int* valor_dos = 25`i'm changing the value inside the `valor_dos`variable and not it's pointer.

Comment: mayhem, doing `int* valor_dos = 25;` set the pointer to address 25, doing `int* valor_dos; *valor_dos = 25;` let the pointer undefined and write 25 at an undefined address. The closest correct match to you want to do is `int v; int* valor_dos = &v; *valor_dos = 25` which will set the pointer to a place where you are allowed to write, then write 25 there. You could also do a `malloc()` instead of instantiating `v`, but dynamic allocation is more difficult to handle if you are a beginner in C.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
 int *valor_dos = 25;
```

you are initializing a pointer to an int with the value 25 .. I.e.,it points at memory location 25, that can only lead to trouble. I'm surprised you didn't get a seg fault.

Comment: There's no segfault because the pointer wasn't reassigned.  The union of our two answers I think is the right answer. :-)

Comment: @nhathdh- Sorry... is there an error in the post?  I'm not sure what you want me to change.

Answer (score -2):

```
int *valor_dos = 25
```

This statement is incorrect. You are declaring a pointer here, so you cannot assign a value (25) to it.

Comment: You *can* do this (this is C, after all), but it's just a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: Yes you *can* do this. Pointers are just integers.

Comment: @templatetypedef Exactly, one of C's *strengths* is *also* one of its major *weaknesses*, it will happily do whatever you ask it to do :-/

Comment: You can assign anything without problem. The problem is when you dereference the pointer. If you are lucky (or unlucky when you are debugging), you will not get a SEGFAULT.

Comment: However, the convention is to use hex notation whenever assigning an integer value to a pointer, addresses are always expressed in hex. If the code doesn't use hex notation, but as in this case decimal, then it is most likely a bug.